# LV partition resize issue - parted cannot satisfy all constraints while resizing /dev/sda3

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, parted

In my virtualbox vm, initially there was 25GB of disk space. Via vbox media manager, I have increased the size to 50GB. The next plan was to use parted to carry out the resize.

These are the state of my disks (outputs of fdisk and df):

[image]

I am trying to increase the size of the logical volume. First instinct was to increase /dev/sda3

Via parted (via an ssh session) I try to resize /dev/sda3

But I get the error message saying that it cannot satisfy all the constraints. (Error not shown).

What are the correct sequence of steps I must perform for the resize?